# Joomla Jdatabase access does not work

Tags: php, sql, joomla

I just started to learn about joomla (3.x) and installed a part of the example component with a view and model (reference [http://docs.joomla.org/J3.3:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_a_model_to_the_site_part](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.3%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Adding_a_model_to_the_site_part)).

When I added some database code to the model -see below- I got the error message:

```
The requested page cannot be found.

An error has occurred while processing your request.

#0  SQL=SELECT username FROM '#__users' WHERE id='391'
```

I assume my query is wrong (I deliberately used the string instead the object for the query), but I don't understand what is wrong with it? (ps: I checked that the table with __users as well as the tablefields id and username exist.

the related code (of model part):

```
                    // Get a db connection.
                    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

                    // Create a new query 
                    //$query = $db->getQuery(true); //Option A: Create a new query object
                    $query = "SELECT username FROM '#__users' WHERE id='391' "; //Option B (classic method): SQL query string
                    $db->setQuery($query);

                    //Execute query
                    $db->execute();

                    //Get single DB result
                    //if($result)
                     $this->msg = 'Hello '.$db->loadResult();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stick to Joomla coding standards for your query like so:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo(); 
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName('username'))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__users'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . (int) 391));

$db->setQuery($query);    
$result = $db->loadResult();
```

But if you are trying to get the username of s user with a specific ID, then you can simply use the following:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser(391);
$this->msg = 'Hello '. $user->get('username');
```

Comment: Thnx Lodder; I actually just concluded the same when I used the object. But I'm still curious why the string alternative does not work? http://api.joomla.org/cms-2.5/classes/JDatabase.html#method_setQuery says: "$query
mixedThe SQL statement to set either as a JDatabaseQuery object OR A STRING." I assume (and hope) EVERY kind of SQL statement is possible with the object structure (?)

Comment: You forgot to get the current query object using this: http://api.joomla.org/cms-2.5/classes/JDatabase.html#method_getQuery ...for more information on database queries with examples, have a look at this: http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: If I interpret the setQuery method well (http://api.joomla.org/cms-2.5/classes/JDatabase.html#method_setQuery) you only needs to use the getQuery method beforehand if you uses indeed the object. But if you use the string, caalling the getQuery method is not needed (?)

Comment: You're right, calling getQuery() isn't required. The problem you're having is that you have two name entities in the SQL `username` and `#_users` but you have one, the table name, quoted incorrectly this appears to prevent JDatabase from quoting both entities properly. That's why @Lodder's code works he's using `quoteName()` around both named entities. Your code with work by using the correct quoting, eg.:  `$query = "SELECT ". $db->quoteName('username') ." FROM ". $db->quoteName('#__users) . " WHERE id='391'"`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your quoting the table name, when backticks (at most) should be used. Backticks really only need to be used in the event that your table name shares with a reserved mysql name.

```
"SELECT username FROM `#__users` WHERE id=391 "
```

Side note, INT values don't need encapsulation.

Comment: thnx. I tried your suggestion but still get the error message #0  SQL=SELECT username FROM '#__users' WHERE id=391

Comment: @Joppo Copy + pasta this into your SQL execute in PHPMyAdmin. same error?